# Can I transfer my Australian ETA to my new passport or must I re-apply?

Tags: australia, eta, malaysian-citizens

I have a situation where my current ETA is still valid till 14th February 2020 on my existing Malaysian Passport that will have less than 4 months validity at the end of my trip (will arrive on 30th Oct and depart from Australia on 10th Nov 2019), and will apply for a new Malaysian Passport to meet the minimum 6 months Passport validity, my questions are as follows:

1. Can I transfer the current ETA that expires on 14th February 2020 to my new Passport?
2. If the reply to (1) is no, I have to assume that I need to reapply for a 
    new ETA with my new Passport?

Answer (score 14):

Unlike other Australian visas, the ETA is [not transferable](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601) to a new passport. If you get a new passport, you must [apply for a new ETA](https://www.eta.homeaffairs.gov.au/ETAS3/etas) with the new passport.

You should also be aware that the six month passport validity rule does not apply to Australia; your passport only needs to be valid for the duration of your journey. This means you do not need a new passport before your travel to Australia next month. You can renew it after you return home.

Comment: Yet others say a passport is no good within 3 months of expiry, and others till say a passport functionally expires at 6 months prior to expiry.  Is there really a different rule for each country and situation, and you have to research each individual case?

Comment: @Harper, yes you have to check for each pair of countries to be sure, as some countries have a blanket 'left over time needed' but have exceptions on that for some countries.

Comment: Australia doesn't appear to have a six month rule (or any month rule) for any nationality's passports.